# Where to place the script tag in a Angular App

Tags: angular

I was working on a SDK for an Angular app.

I could either use the npm package for the library else I could use the script tag.

I placed the script tag in the index.html thinking it should be available to any component. However that didn't work. But through npm package it worked. Just wondering why the script tag didn't work. Any guess please.

Comment: it will work, just the import statement is different

instead of import, you need to use declare
```
declare var PackageName
```

Comment: If it's a `npm` package then you should add it in `angular.json`.

Comment: declare var PackageName worked! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try having a look at the [Angular documentation for adding libraries that can't be imported into an app in the usual way](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#adding-a-library-to-the-runtime-global-scope). In short: You don't have to add script-tags to the index.html manually. Instead, you can install the npm package and add the script to your angular.json. There, you will find an array called "scripts" where you can link the script that was downloaded into node_modules:

```
"scripts": [
  // just an example:
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
  // place the path to your script here
],
```